# facebook how to know in what applications user is register

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

i'm building a facebook based mobile application.
every time a user is logging into my server, i want know which of his friends has accepted my application in facebook.
what i'm doing now is that i'm sending my server the list of the user's friend, and returning to him a list of whom from is friend is also a member of my application.
the problem is that this process is real slow when a user have lots of friends..

is there a way throw graph api or FQL to check to which applications a user (or his friend) granted permissions ?

Comment: i've actually didn't try anything, i couldn't find how it is done.
but i am looking now in the facebook FQL and graph API inside application method, looking if can see it users...

Comment: i think i've found that i can try to get it with the api using:
https://graph.facebook.com/app_id/subscriptions with my application access_token. but trying that always tells me that i need to get application_access_token, although i used it for the query. i think maybe because my application is native

Comment: You have to check this http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/

Comment: i have, that where i found what i've written, but none of these field can return me a list of users who added the application...
even inside user fql table, i didn't found an application list..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you mark your app as native, Facebook disable the app access token from making API requests - this is a security measure to protect the developer and the users because most native apps will distribute their app secret, so it cannot be trusted.

That said, there is currently no way to retrieve a list of an app's users via Graph API or FQL. My recommendation is that you should track this at authorisation time - the point at which you get an access token for a user - because you can then store a full list of UIDs in your own database and not rely on the API for that list.

As a possible workaround (assuming you haven't been doing what I recommended above and have a number of users already), if you have stored access tokens somewhere, you could iterate through those and make a call to `https://graph.facebook.com/me` for each, which should give you the UIDs of all your app users. You may not have stored the access tokens centrally though, in which case I'm afraid you will not be able to get this list.

Comment: Yes that what i thougt... im already doing my own list of users.. i thought i could be more efficient..